# After deployment, one Rancher load balanced RESTful app instance returns 404 while other returns results

Tags: docker, load-balancing, devops, gitlab-ci, rancher

I hope you can help me with this issue.

I have setup a CI/CD pipeline which triggers builds, packages, and deploys tasks that execute on Gitlab online whenever a Spring boot RESTful service app is checked in. The three stages and tasks run successfully but whenever I test the app by navigating to the load balancer URL in a browser, I discover that one load balancer target returns (type=Not Found, status=404) error, while the other target returns the JSON response that is expected. The load balancer defaults to a round-robin algorithm in the distribution of requests to targets.

The infrastructure provider is Digital Ocean.

What am I doing wrong?

Kindly find below the .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: gitlab-ci

stages:
  - build
  - package
  - deploy

maven-build:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: build
  script: "mvn package -B"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar

docker-build:
  stage: package
  script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
  - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/username/mta-hosting-optimizer .
  - docker push registry.gitlab.com/username/mta-hosting-optimizer

digitalocean-deploy:
  image: cdrx/rancher-gitlab-deploy
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - upgrade --environment Default --stack mta-hosting-optimizer --service web --new-image registry.gitlab.com/username/mta-hosting-optimizer
  - upgrade --environment Default --stack mta-hosting-optimizer --service web2 --new-image registry.gitlab.com/username/mta-hosting-optimizer
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/username/mta-hosting-optimizer:latest
    ports:
    - 8082:8080/tcp
  mta-hosting-optimizer-lb:
    image: rancher/lb-service-haproxy:v0.9.1
    ports:
    - 80:80/tcp
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.agent.role: environmentAdmin,agent
      io.rancher.container.agent_service.drain_provider: 'true'
      io.rancher.container.create_agent: 'true'
  web2:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/username/mta-hosting-optimizer:latest
    ports:
    - 8082:8080/tcp
```

rancher-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    scale: 1
    start_on_create: true
  mta-hosting-optimizer-lb:
    scale: 1
    start_on_create: true
    lb_config:
      certs: []
      port_rules:
      - path: ''
        priority: 1
        protocol: http
        service: web
        source_port: 80
        target_port: 8080
      - priority: 2
        protocol: http
        service: web2
        source_port: 80
        target_port: 8080
    health_check:
      response_timeout: 2000
      healthy_threshold: 2
      port: 42
      unhealthy_threshold: 3
      initializing_timeout: 60000
      interval: 2000
      reinitializing_timeout: 60000
  web2:
    scale: 1
    start_on_create: true
```

> Edited to provide the haproxy.cfg file below in response to @leodotcloud's
>   request

```
global
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    daemon
    group haproxy
    maxconn 4096
    maxpipes 1024
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tls-tickets
    ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA
    stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 600 level admin
    stats timeout 2m
    user haproxy

defaults
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
    maxconn 4096
    mode tcp
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    option redispatch
    retries 3
    timeout client 50000
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout server 50000

resolvers rancher
 nameserver dnsmasq xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53

listen default
bind *:42

frontend 80
bind *:80
mode http
default_backend 80_

backend 80_
acl forwarded_proto hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Proto) eq 0
acl forwarded_port hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Port) eq 0
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if forwarded_port
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } forwarded_proto
mode http
server 89fbd2fd02e5b178c8c60ecf5ddc74yyyyyyyyyy xx.xx.166.99:8080
server 30c794d4a7524307ae3244a602caf1yyyyyyyyyy xx.xx.158.63:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward answer to your question but here are some pointers to debug your problem:

- I see there are two web services (web, web2) being deployed with port 8082. Are there enough hosts to expose both of these ports.
- Are both web and web2 containers running successfully or are there any failures?
- Is the networking plugin running successfully in the cluster?
- Is the cross host networking working properly between the hosts in the cluster?
- Is the Loadbalancer configured properly? (Execute shell into the lb container and check for haproxy.cfg)

If none of these help you to root cause the problem, please file an issue with https://github.com/rancher/rancher.

Comment: thank you very much; everything seems fine. Each service container and the load balancer container are each running exclusively on a host in a one container per host arrangement. The web and web 2 services are running successfully without any failures. The Rancher-recommended and default managed network is what I am using and therefore this caters to cross-host networking. I have edited my response above to add the haproxy.cfg file from the load balancer container.

Answer (score 0):

What's likely happening is that the first web container to start gets the port (8080) and the second one isn't able to bind to it. Even if the two containers are running on different nodes, Swarm can't assign that port to them both due to the way that it routes requests through the service mesh.

See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#publish-a-services-ports-directly-on-the-swarm-node

Also this issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33160

To solve this, configure the web containers to run on different ports. Or, since it looks like you want to run two instances of the same container, increase the numbers of replicas of the `web` service. Swarm will distribute the containers across the available nodes for you.

HAProxy only needs to load balance your nodes, but really if you hit any of your nodes' IP addresses, the request may be routed within Swarm to another node, since the entire cluster of machines becomes load balanced within Swarm itself. It's two layers of load balancing: within the Swarm cluster after a request hits one of the nodes and between the client and your infrastructure.